# Failure to link a program with gcc -static

Tags: c, gcc

I'm trying to compile and link the following code with gcc:

```
#include <stdlib.h>

main()
{
    exit(0);
}
```

I'm using  `gcc -static -o exit exit.c`

I get the following error:

```
/usr/bin/ld: cannot find -lc
collect2: ld returned 1 exit status
```

What does this mean and how can I fix this?

Comment: it means it can't find libc, the standard C library. Why? I don't know.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In particular, it means it can't find the *static* version of the C library, because you are compiling with `-static`.  This means that it can't use the standard shared library, typically something like `/lib/libc.so`.

In order to support building static binaries, you would need to install the appropriate static library (`libc.a`), which may or may not be available in pre-packaged format for your distribution.  Under Fedora, this is available as the `glibc-static` package:

```
yum install glibc-static
```

With this package installed, I can build a static binary from your sample code without a problem:

```
$ gcc -static -o exit exit.c
$ file exit
exit: ELF 64-bit LSB executable, x86-64, version 1 (GNU/Linux),
statically linked, for GNU/Linux 2.6.32,
BuildID[sha1]=12c642ecc01622c623c2efa5efa7e23d73889808, not stripped
```

Other solutions include building the static C library yourself, or working with a smaller C library designed for embedding, such as [uclibc](http://www.uclibc.org/) or [musl](http://www.musl-libc.org/).  These are smaller and typically more amendable to static linking.  This would may *also* involve building the library yourself.